# Why is the map $T(x,y)=(x,xy)$ not ergodic on $S^1\times S^1$.

Tags: ergodic-theory

Here is my reasoning. I use multiplicative notation.

Let $f \in L^2$ then it has a Fourier series $$f(x,y)=\sum a_{n,m}x^ny^m$$ because $x^ny^m$ are characters and so they form an orthonormal basis. Now $$f(T(x,y))=\sum a_{n,m}x^{n+m}y^m.$$ If $f$ is $T$ invariant then it must be that $a_{n,m}=a_{n+m,m}=a_{n+2m,m}=...$ Thus unless $a_{n,m}$ are zero this the coefficents are not square summable. The series
$$\sum a_{n,m}x^{n+m}y^m$$ is a Fourier series as $x^{n+m}y^m$ are disinct charcters for all $n,m$.

Where is my mistake? My books says this map is not ergodic.

Edit: Is $m=0$ perhaps the problem here? since $a_{n,0}$ might still be non-zero. If so, I demand a refund of my time i spent staring at this

Comment: What is $K/S^1$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan that is just my terrible notation. I mean $S^1$ but i use multiplicative notation where the notation is $K$ in my book.

Comment: It might help if you tell us what book you are using.

Comment: @RobArthan Peter Walkers, introduction to ergodic theory.

Comment: Is $S^1$ the unit circle?  If so, what is $(x,y) \in S^1$?

Comment: @Adam Good catch! its $S^1 \times S^1$

Comment: This map is called a "Dehn twist" and they are never ergodic. You should take an Anosov map instead.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Again, I know this map is not ergodic. I am looking for the reason why my proof is faulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean with respect to Lebesgue measure: $f(x,y) = x$ is a non-constant $T$-invariant function.

In the Fourier series for this $f$ you have all $a_{n,m}=0$ except for $a_{1,0}=1$. So you were correct when you guessed that the coefficients with m=0 create the problem with your original proof

Comment: I know I am wrong. I just do not see where I am wrong

Comment: In the Fourier series for this $f$ you have all $a_{n,m} = 0$ except for $a_{1,0} = 1$.  So you were correct when you guessed that the coefficients with $m = 0$ create the problem with your original proof

Comment: Follow up question, is the map $T(x,y)=(xe^{2\pi i \alpha},xy)$ ergodic for $\alpha$ non integer? Using this argument + the change in the first coordinate allows us to conclude $a_{n,0}=0$ for all $n>0$

Comment: Yes it is, in fact it is uniquely ergodic with Lebesgue measure as the unique invariant measure.  This is a result originally due to Furstenberg and you can find a nice proof in (for example) Einsiedler and Ward's book

Comment: Thank you very much Adam, that was very helpful. Could you put the comment in the answer? So that it is complete.